# What does it mean to "smoothly deform" one basis to another?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

The following is a passage from the page 121 of *Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Space* by Shurman et al.

> Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $F$ be the matrix formed by their columns. The multilinear function $\det(F)$ is continuous in the $n^2$ entries of $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$. If a basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ can be **smoothly deformed** via other bases to the standard basis then the corresponding determinants must change continuously to $1$.

The authors do not touch the definition of a *smooth deformation* from this point to an exercise which asks to argue that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ every basis can be smoothly deformed via other bases to the standard basis or $\{e_1, -e_2\}$. So what does one mean by a smooth deformation in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis and $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ is another basis, a smooth deformation that changes the first one into the second one is a smooth map $\Gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow(\Bbb R^n)^n$ such that

- $\Gamma(0)=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$;
- $\Gamma(1)=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$;
- if $t\in[0,1]$ and $\Gamma(t)=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$, then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think you mean $\Gamma:[0,1]\to (\Bbb{R}^n)^n$ (and in the first line $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}$, not $f_2$ haha)